# MIPS Values arent able to be accessed from memory

Tags: arrays, sorting, mips

So the issue is that whenever i try to access the integers placed into the array which seems to work perfectly and theyre even saved to an address of +0 and +4 respectively and so on for the amount of values there are but when i attempt to take them out to use them for sorting purposes they're seemingly not being loaded into the $t4 and $t5 values. below is my code im using for this, why wont the values transfer when loading them from 0,4($s1) where they are placed?

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the array size \n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter integers to fill the array \n"
prompt3: .asciiz "Sorted Array: "

.text

main:
li $t0, 0
la $a0, prompt1
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t0, $v0 #array size
add $t9, $t0, $t0
li $v0, 9
la $a0, ($t0)
syscall
move $s0, $v0 #array address w/ size in memory
add $s1, $zero, $s0
loop:
la $a0, prompt2
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $v0, 5
syscall

beqz $t0, sort
sw $v0, 0($s1)
addiu $s1, $s1, 4
subiu $t0, $t0, 1
bnez $t0, loop


sort:
lw $t4, 0($s1)
lw $t5, 4($s1)
blt $t5, $t4, swap
addiu $s1, $s1, 4
subiu $t9, $t9, 1
bnez $t9, sort

j exit
swap:
sw $t4, 4($s1)
sw $t5, 0($s1)

exit:
```

Comment: `la $a0, ($t0)` <-- that's a pretty weird way of expressing what you could achieve with the much clearer `move $a0,$t0`. Also, syscall 9 allocates `$a0` number of *bytes*. If you want to allocate that same number of *words* you have to multiplicate the number by 4. As for the problem in your question, the solution is simple: place breakpoints at relevant places in your code and inspect the contents of registers and memory until you find where your mistake is.

Comment: Where would i go about in the code multiplying that number, before or after the syscall 9? For some reason now after applying this im getting at error on the line `sw $v0, 0(s1) when attempting to save the integer. It seems that  prior to this change the contents are being saved in memory but arent able to be accessed and plugged into a register and thats where im getting confused as to why thats occuring. Thank you for your help!